# Magento 2, show first product image if no role assigned

Tags: image, magento2

Sometimes i have a product with only 1 image. I down want to select each role for the product image. But if i don't select the image roles, magento shows the default placeholder.

Is there anyway to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate on your question with more details, and provide some screenshots of what exactly you want to achieve. Do you have a simple or configurable product?

For the placeholders, that's default behavior but either way:

- you can set the placeholder image (*Note that will be changed for every product*)
- Check the image of the product uploaded correctly
- Check if the base, the small thumbnail image, is set.

For details please ref: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-magento-2-product-types/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33089224)

Comment: Please change the description of your question with some more relevant information.